# Angular 5 Google Material Button Not Opening Page

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm trying to have a button open to a new site, which seems quite straightforward but for some reason this snippet of code isn't working.

`<button mat-raised-button href="https://www.google.com/" color="primary">Connect with Stripe</button>`

I've also tried `ng-href` which didn't work either.

Anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

buttons don't have a href attribute, and aren't used to navigate. Use a link:

```
<a mat-raised-button href="https://www.google.com/" color="primary">Connect with Stripe</a>
```